# Horizontal Nav Bar coming up as vertical

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
<style> 
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}
.topnav1 {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.topnav1:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
.topnav1.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
.homebutton {
  width: 5%;
  height: auto;
  border: solid;
  border-color: white float: left;
  align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav topnav1">
        <a href="/" class="topnav topnav1"><img src="imagesource" class="homebutton"></img>
        </a>
        <a href="/about" class="topnav topnav1">About</a>
        <a href="/updates" class="topnav topnav1">Updates</a>
        <a href="/contact" class="topnav topnav1">Contact</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to design a navigation bar with a photo for the home button, however the bar I am trying to design is horizontal and fixed at the top of the page.  However it keeps coming up as vertical and centered to the top of the page.  How can this be fixed.

Comment: Remove class `topnav`  from each a/link  tag in your Div

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below show structure.
You really need to work a lot on your `CSS`. And from wherever you are learning, do also check those properties and their current support by browsers.

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.topnav1 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: auto;
}

.topnav1:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav1.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.homebutton {
  width: 5%;
  height: auto;
  border: solid;
  border-color: white float: left;
  text-align: center;
  /* Align:center is obsolete now */
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="/" class="topnav1"><img src="imagesource" class="homebutton">
  </a>
  <a href="/about" class="topnav1">About</a>
  <a href="/updates" class="topnav1">Updates</a>
  <a href="/contact" class="topnav1">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, so i tried this and now the image is on top with the rest of the links below in horizontal form, rather than to the left of the other links.

Comment: @VictorCleare can you share the Fiddle link

Comment: what is a fiddle link?

Comment: similar to above `code-snippet`. You can copy-paste your HTML,CSS there. https://jsfiddle.net/